# Making a matrix positive definite by adding terms to the diagonal

Tags: linear-algebra

If matrix $A$ is not positive definite, at least one eigenvalue is less than or equal to zero. Let us call the smallest eigenvalue $\nu$ and the associate eigenvector by $x$. If I want to make this matrix positive definite, I need to add a damping term $\lambda$ to the diagonals. Now, as far as I remember that $\lambda$ needs to be a very small positive value. However, my analysis says it needs to be larger than the smallest eigenvalue. I am unsure if my analysis is correct or if my prior knowledge is.

$$B = A + \lambda I, Bx = Ax + \lambda x = (\nu  + \lambda)x $$

So to make $B$ PD, I need to add $\lambda > \nu$ to the diagonals.

Can you confirm if my analysis is correct or I am missing something?

Comment: Your analysis is correct, and your memory isn't.

Comment: @TheoBendit I always thought that I just need any small number to make a (covriance) matrix PD. I don't know why but when I wanted to prove it, I got this :)

Comment: It is a true fact that an arbitrarily small positive value $\lambda$ is enough to make sure $A+\lambda I$ is not singular (in case $A$ is singular); maybe that's what you were remembering.

Comment: @MishaLavrov Yes, you are right. Thanks for the correction.